# Use Windows 'Mobile hotspot' with OpenVPN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

I've set up an OpenVPN server, and my PC successfully connects through it, routing all traffic through the server.

My end goal is to have my Android phone's traffic also be routed through the server. I would like to accomplish that by connecting the phone to the PC's mobile hotspot. However, the traffic from the hotspot is not routed through the OpenVPN, rather through my regular wi-fi. How can I change that?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it's pretty simple.

Open the network adapter's control panel page (`WIN`+`R` for run, enter `ncpa.cpl`). Right-click the OpenVPN adapter, choose `Properties`. In the dialog that opens, go to the `Sharing` tab, and enable Internet Sharing, selecting the mobile hotspot connection to share with.